# Handling Parent-Child Relationship using MVP within a WinForms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

I recently asked on [**Programmers**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/):

[**How should one handle a Parent-Child relationship using MVP?**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257069/how-should-one-handle-a-parent-child-relationship-using-mvp)

Based on the comments received, I tried this:

**IParentView**

```
public interface IParentView { }
```

**IChildView**

```
public interface IChildView<V> where V : IParentView {
    void Show(V parentView);
}
```

**IChildPresenter**

```
public interface IChildPresenter<V> where V : IParentView {
    void ShowView(V parentView);
}
```

**CustomerManagementPresenter**

```
public class CustomerManagementPresenter : Presenter<ICustomerManagementView>
    , ICustomerManagementUiHandler
    , IChildViewPresenter<IMainView> {
    public CustomerManagementPresenter(ICustomerManagementView view
        , ICustomerManagementService service) : base(view) {
        view.Handler = this;
        if (service == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("service");
        customerManagementService = service;
    }

    public void LoadCustomers() {
        var customers = customerManagementService.GetCustomers();
        View.ViewModel.Customers = customers;
    }

    public void ShowView(IMainView parentView) { View.Show(parentView); }

    private readonly ICustomerManagementService customerManagementService;
}
```

**IMainView**

```
public interface IMainView : IView, IParentView, IHasUiHandler<IMainViewUiHandler> { }
```

**MainPresenter**

```
public class MainPresenter : Presenter<IMainView>, IMainViewUiHandler {
    public MainPresenter(IMainView view, ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory factory)
        : base(view) {
        view.Handler = this;
        if (factory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("factory");
        this.customerManagementPresenterFactory = factory;
    }

    public void ManageCustomers() {
        var p = customerManagementPresenterFactory.Create();
        var parent = this.View;
        p.ShowView(parent);
    }
}
```

**CustomerManagementForm**

```
public partial class CustomerManagementForm : Form, IMainView {
    public CustomerManagementForm(CustomerManagementViewModel viewModel) {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (viewModel == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("viewModel");

        customerManagementViewModel = viewModel;
        customerManagementViewModel.PropertyChanged += 
            new PropertyChangedEventHandler(
                customerManagementViewModel_PropertyChanged);
    }

    public ICustomerManagementUiHandler Handler { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Title { get { return Text; } set { Text = value; } }
    public CustomerManagementViewModel ViewModel { 
        get { return customerManagementViewModel; } 
    }    

    public void Show(IMainView parent) {
        MdiParent = (Form)parent;
        Show();
    }    

    private void CustomerManagementForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Handler.LoadCustomers();
    }

    private void CustomerManagementViewModel_PropertyChanged(
        object sender
        , PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        customerManagementViewModelBindingSource.DataSource = ViewModel;
    }

    private readonly CustomerManagementViewModel customerManagementViewModel;
}
```

I believe I could reduce complexity or repetition with my **IChildPresenter** and **IChildView** which are pretty similar. Besides, The `Show()` methods belongs expressly to the views, whilst `ShowView()` methods actually belongs to presenters. I tend to follow some such basic nomenclature to make it more understandable.

So now I wonder, what do you guys think of this approach?

Did I miss the point?

Any possible imporvement?

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert in design patterns, but I fail to see the benefit in having a completely empty interface.

> ```
> public interface IParentView { }
> ```

Interfaces do two things for us.

1. They enforce a contract. Anything implementing this interface ***must*** have this specific public api. Which allows for...
2. The ability to code against an expected api, not an implementation.

While you've done a good job of coding against `IParentView` instead of `IChildView`, what does the parent view get us? Nothing as far as I can tell. There's no real contract being made here, so there's no reason you couldn't have coded directly against `IChildView`. (Which, at that point, would not be a good name.)

But don't take just my word for it, [24 people on stack overflow agree that this pattern is a code smell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7552819/3198973).

Comment: `IParentView` shall be used as a type constraint, so no other types is passed, except the type I decided to make the parent view, namely `IMainView`. So, this fulfills its role being a contract. As for the default getter/setter, the `Title` is implemented within a `Form`, so changing the `Title` shall actually change the `Form.Text Property`, whilst no control has been defined yet to display the `Message` property to the user.

Comment: I removed the part about the getter/setter, but I still don't think you're getting anything from having an empty interface.

Comment: I mean, yes... you do get the illusion of typesafety of passing an argument as an IParent, but is it really actually type safe if there's no guarantee that `IChildview1` and `IChildView2` actually have compatible APIs?

Comment: Then, one simply doesn't implement the `IChildView`, or does nothing in its implementation. And actually, the use of `IChildView` simply makes sense if one wishes a parent/child UI relationship such as WinForms MDI or the like, otherwise one doesn't need to use the `IChildView` interface.

Comment: I have read further on the linked post and the pattern I use is actually called a `Marker Interface Pattern`, and even Java uses it with its `Serializeable` interface. The other way around is to use `Custom` attributes. There's a point I find interesting with the `Marker Interface Pattern`, that is the compile-time check, which won't be using `Custom Attributes`. Somehow I get your your point and agree, and I also agree with my point of view. I'd like to get further details on this topic.